# Uniqueness activerecord validation in a list for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a user model and a Request model,

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w(PENDING
                                         RUNNING
                                         COMPLETED
                                         FAILED
                                         ERROR) }

  validates :status, on: :create,
                     uniqueness: { scope: :user_id,
                                   message: "There is another request for this user",
                                   conditions: -> { where(status: ['PENDING',
                                                                   'RUNNING',
                                                                   'ERROR']) }

  }

end
```

The idea behind the uniqueness validation is that you cannot create a Request for that user if he has another PENDING, RUNNING or ERROR request.

```
it 'cannot a new pending request if user allredy has another RUNNING task' do
  described_class.create!(user: user, status: 'RUNNING')

  expect { described_class.create!(user: user) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, 
                                                                /There is another request for this user/)
end
```

This test fails because It can create another Request even when another RUNNING request was created.

I guess that is because I doing something wrong on the condition.

This is the migration that creates Request model.

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.integer :reason
      t.string  :status, default: 'PENDING', :limit => 15
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :requests
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the default status? Do you have any in migration?

Comment: PENDING is the default status.

Comment: I've added the Request model's migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to do too much with the `validates ... uniqueness:` built-in method. The method assumes that the column value must be **unique**, not *unique within a collection*.

(Your attempt to define this within the `conditions` parameter seems reasonable, but this only actually limits the scope of records being compared *against*; it does not alter the definition of "unique column" to mean "unique within a list".)

I would suggest instead writing this validation as a custom method - for example, something like:

```
validate :unique_status_within_collection, on: :create

def unique_status_within_collection
  unique_statuses = ['PENDING', 'RUNNING', 'ERROR']
  if unique_statuses.include?(status) && Request.exists?(user: user, status: unique_statuses)
    errors.add(:status, "There is another request for this user")
  end
end
```

Comment: Might as well share this, for reference.... Here's a brand new, minimal rails project with the above test, passing: https://github.com/tom-lord/uniqueness_validation_test

Comment: Thank you Tom, I thought that it would be solved with uniqueness. But seems to be many conditions for that uniqueness validation. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by using an [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) instead. First make `requests.status` an integer column with an index instead of varchar.

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.integer :reason
      t.integer :status, default: 0, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :requests, [:user_id, :status]
  end
end
```

You should also use `t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true` to setup a foreign key for the user association. Specifying up and down blocks is not needed - just specify the change block and ActiveRecord is smart enough to know how to reverse it on its own.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this defaults to true in Rails 5.
  belongs_to :user, required: true
  enum status: [:pending, :running, :completed, :failed, :error]
  validate :unique_status_within_collection, on: :create

  def unique_status_within_collection
    unique_statuses = %w[ pending running error]
    if unique_statuses.includes?(self.status) && user.requests.exists?(status: unique_statuses)
      errors.add(:base, "There is another request for this user")
    end
  end
end
```

One huge gotcha though is that the name `request` already is really significant in rails and if you use the instance variable `@request` in the controller you're masking the incoming request object.

I would rename it something like "UserRequest" or whatever to avoid this ambiguity.